# maven-glassfish-plugin remote delopy from windows IDE to linux Server

Tags: maven, deployment, glassfish, maven-plugin, maven-glassfish-plugin

I want to deploy to a remote Linux server with maven-glassfish-plugin 2.1.

But the plugin always try to call **`C:\...\asadmin.bat`**. Here are the error msg:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project LottoEarth: Deployment of D:\workspaces\eclipse-kepler\Project\target\myProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war failed. IOException: Cannot run program "D:\opt\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden -> [Help 1]`

I tried to declare the OS  in my Profile but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missunderstood that i have to use a local glassfish (asadmin.bat) to delpoy on the remote Linux-Server. So here is an example configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <glassfishDirectory>C:\glassfish3\glassfish</glassfishDirectory>
                    <user>myRemoteAdmin</user>
                    <adminPassword>myRemoteAdminPassword</adminPassword>
                    <domain>
                        <name>myRemoteDomain</name>
                        <host>myRemoteHost</host>
                        <adminPort>myRemoteAdminPort(4848)</adminPort>
                    </domain>
                </configuration>
....
<plugin>
```